# How do i get the image in the back of my form

Tags: html, css, image, forms

I want to get my image behind my form but I can't get it right.
I hope someone can help me fix this because this looks awful.

These are mij codes:

```
        <div id ="content">
                <form>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Gebruikersnaam
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type ="text"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Paswoord
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type ="password"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form> 
            </div> 


    #content {
        clear: both;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 50%;
        background-image:url('login.png');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        min-height: 461px;
      }
```

You can find the [example](http://nl.tinypic.com/r/nyvb77/5) here.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle ?

Comment: Can you try using overflow:hidden property

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/FdUgp/

```
#content {
        clear: both;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 400px;
        background-color: red;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        min-height: 300px;
        text-align: center;
      }
#content form {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Put the width and the height of the #content with the exactlty same size of your image, and later change the margin-top of the form to match the position you want.

If you want some responsive this is a little more tricky.
Look the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FdUgp/2/

Key points are:

- background-size: cover for your image resize with the #content.
- The :before pseudoelement to make height of the #content responsive.
- The relative/absolute positioning of the form.
- The text-align: center and the display:inline-block moved to the form/table instead of the content/form.

Comment: How can I make ik little responsive? I want to use % in place of px

Answer (score 0):

Try background-position:center top; or background-position: top;

Answer (score 0):

You could use a padding value on `#content` to push the form left and down.

I would also consider removing the table elements, it's never great for a layout to use tables. There are much better more consistent and flexible methods of achieving the same thing.

Also, try and post a live example or a JSfiddle so people can see your code in action.